# Serialize a json field as a string

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a pojo that I am unmarshalling a REST response to. One of the fields ("errors") is just a list of plain Strings for the majority of the rest methods. However, for a couple of the methods, the field is a list of json-formatted strings. Jackson doesn't seem to like this, as it throws an UnrecognizedPropertyException for these responses.

Is there a way to tell it to treat the field as a plain string for all cases instead of trying to deserialize to an object?

Here's a trimmed down piece of the class it's unmarshalling to, and an example of a response that works and a response that fails:

```
public class UpdateResult {
    public List<String> errors;

    @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
    public List<String> getErrors() {
        return this.errors;
    }
    public void setErrors(final List<String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }
}
```

Works:

```
"{"errors":["errorMsg1","errorMsg2"]}"
```

Fails:

```
"{"errors":[{"errorType":"type1"},{"errorType":"type2"}]}"
```

Comment: What `List<String> errors` list property should contains in second example?

Comment: I would like it to treat it as a String, exactly as it is seen. Like: ["{"errorType":"type1"}", "{"errorType":"type2"}"].

Comment: You want to achieve something like that: `[{errorType=type1}, {errorType=type2}]` or `[{"errorType":"type1"}, {"errorType":"type2"}]`?

Comment: `errors` is JSON array of entities.  In one case the entities are Strings, in the other case JSON "objects" (which will become Maps).  Simply deserialize `errors` as a List and then examine the type of the elements of the List, so see if they are Strings or Maps.

Comment: @HotLicks Are you suggesting I deserialize as a raw type list? So, `List errors` rather than `List<String> errors`?

Comment: Well, `List<Object>` if you want to avoid the `@#$%`compiler complaints.  Then `isInstanceOf` will let you sort things out.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing, and it does the trick. Thanks.